# PostCSS via Gulp file concatenation before output

Tags: gulp, postcss

Is it possible to configure `gulp.src()` or `gulp.dest()` to generate a single file from multiple in files?

```
gulp.src(['!node_modules/','**/*.css'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps:true}))
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_FOLDER));
```

The code above produces an output file for each input file (1-to-1) and sourcemaps for each.

Do I need to pipe a concat task for that to happen or can it be done via options for the two gulp methods mentioned above?

Thanks.